# Jpa Objet has null value on the references

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have an object returned by a Hibernate Query, an object which should have a list of replacements in it. 
So, I have an "order" Object which should have a "Replacement" Set in it, the problem is that when I lookup that list, this is what i get `com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.` and then, when the code keeps running and I try to acces that set, this is what I get `failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: uo.ri.model.Order.ReplacementList, no session or session was closed`

I Really have no idea why I'm having this error, I'm going to paste here my `Order` and my `Replacement` classes, hope you can solve it

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TOrder")
public class Order implements Serializable {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue
    long id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date creation_date;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date reception_date;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private PedidoStatus status;
    private float price;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
    private Set<PedidoRepuesto> replacementList= new HashSet<PedidoRepuesto>();
    @ManyToOne
    private Proveedor provider;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "TReplacement")
public class Repuesto implements Serializable {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue
    long id;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int having;
    private int likeToHave;
    private int minimumToHave;
    private int totalHaving;
    private float totalPrice;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "replacement")
    private Set<OrderReplacement> orderReplacements= new HashSet<OrderReplacement>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "replacement")
    private Set<Sustitucion> sustituciones = new HashSet<Sustitucion>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "replacement")
    private Set<ProviderReplacement> providerReplacement= new HashSet<ProviderReplacement>();
}
```

Both clases has the getters/setters and constructors.

If you need me to paste here more clases or something please just ask.
Thank you so much.

Comment: did you try putting your list `fetch=FetchType.Eager`

Comment: No, didn't try, but in the database the equivalent of that list isn't null so, why I'm not reciving any data?

Comment: cause default fetch is lazy , that is it's not query if you don't specify , returns a proxy , and when you really need, there query the db , and may be your session was already close..

Comment: Obh.. I. Get it, but where do I soecify the fetch type? Is an anotation? Or I have to specify by code, in the getter? Thank you, I'll try it soon.

Comment: yep where you put the anotation, but this is not the real solution... the real solution is that your session don't have to close until you finish your work xD.. but if you are always using this collection is not bad putting EAGER

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, It was pretty easy, the thing was that I clossed the session and then I wanted to acces the "Un-mapped" parts of the graph, so, the object was Detached => You only can acces those parts of the graph which are in memory.

The solution was to acces that collection while the session were still oppenes, simply call the method `collection.size()`

Then you can access that collection from everywhere. Hope this help!

Comment: this doesnt seem like the right way to do this, is there not a better more official way to indicate that you want to keep all the records around?